# How to join three mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `course_content` table and `lesson` table like below

```
| course_id | lesson_id | content_id | seq_no |
-----------------------------------------------
|     1     |     1     |     1      |   1    |
|     1     |     1     |     2      |   2    |
|     1     |     5     |     3      |   1    |
|     1     |     5     |     4      |   2    |
|     1     |     8     |    12      |   1    |
-----------------------------------------------


| leson_id | lesson_no | course_id |
------------------------------------    
|    1     |     1     |     1     |
|    5     |     3     |     1     |
|    8     |     2     |     1     |
------------------------------------
```

`offering_assmt` table:

```
| offering_id | lesson_id | assessment_id |
-------------------------------------------
|      11     |     1     |      0        |
|      11     |     5     |      1        |
|      11     |     8     |      3        |
-------------------------------------------
```

I want to have a `next` previous button in my app. When `next` is clicked 
and if the current lesson has a next content query then it should give the next content id. If it does not have the next content then it should jump to the next lesson and first content.

A sequence number for content is seq_no and for lesson is lesson_no. Also, if its current lesson has a assessment_id on the next click then it should give an assessment_id after all content_id are done.

On a previous click, if the content_id is the first content of that lesson then on previous click it should give the assessment_id of the previous lesson (only if assessment_id is a non-zero - otherwise it should proceed to content).

I have made below a query that will jump to content and lesson but i'm unable to do it for assessment_id.

**Next click**:

```
SELECT c.course_id, c.lesson_id, c.content_id, c.seq_no, l.lesson_no
FROM (
    SELECT cl.lesson_no AS curr_lesson_no, cc.seq_no AS curr_seq_no
    FROM course_content cc
        JOIN lesson cl ON cl.lesson_id = cc.lesson_id
    WHERE cc.content_id ='" . $content_id . "'
    ORDER BY cl.lesson_no, cc.seq_no
    LIMIT 1
    ) q
    JOIN lesson l ON l.lesson_no >= q.curr_lesson_no
    JOIN course_content c ON c.lesson_id = l.lesson_id
WHERE c.course_id =1
    AND (
        c.seq_no > q.curr_seq_no
        OR l.lesson_no > q.curr_lesson_no
    )
ORDER BY l.lesson_no, c.seq_no
LIMIT 1
```

**Previous click**:

```
SELECT c.course_id, c.lesson_id, c.content_id, c.seq_no, l.lesson_no
FROM (
    SELECT cl.lesson_no AS curr_lesson_no, cc.seq_no AS curr_seq_no
    FROM course_content cc
        JOIN lesson cl ON cl.lesson_id = cc.lesson_id
    WHERE cc.content_id ='" . $content_id . "'
    ORDER BY cl.lesson_no, cc.seq_no DESC 
    LIMIT 1
    ) q
    JOIN lesson l ON l.lesson_no <= q.curr_lesson_no
    JOIN course_content c ON c.lesson_id = l.lesson_id
WHERE c.course_id =1
    AND (
        c.seq_no < q.curr_seq_no
        OR l.lesson_no < q.curr_lesson_no
    )
ORDER BY l.lesson_no, c.seq_no DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How large is the data set? Why not load the entire thing into a bit of json and handle the pagination client-Side?

Comment: @Strawberry Can you help me out in this? Any method is okay for me

Comment: @Strawberry I want it this way itself. i have query for all except navigating assessment_id on next and previous click